# Number of additions in naive matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, algorithms

In the naive matrix multiplication algorithm where you have 3 loops, the total number of multiplications is $n^2(n)=n^3$ given that we have two matrices each with size $n\times n$. But a proof claims that the number of additions is $(n-1)$, so the total number of additions is $n^2(n-1)$. I don't understand how the number of additions is $(n-1)$ as I think it should be $n$ because whenever we multiply we add that element, so we should have the same number of multiplications $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add $n$ terms there are only $n-1$ additions.  For example, $1+2+3$ has only two additions.  You are making a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Comment: I wish I had found the name for this kind of error earlier! It crops up everywhere.

Comment: @Joe.Thank you very much, but why for boolean product, we would have $n$ or bit operations and not $n+1$ as in addition in traditional matrix multiplication in my question?

Comment: @Avra:  I don't understand this question at all.  What operation are you asking about?

Comment: @RossMillikan. I mean the Boolean product of two matrices has two operations, meet $\cap$ and join $\cup$. The number of join operations, which are equivalent to addition in the above algorithm, is not $(n-1)$, but it's $n$

Comment: I don't know what those operations are on matrices.  I know what they are on sets, where there are $n-1$ operations on $n$ sets.